# I know something to be being done?

Tags: grammar

a)  I see the frog green.

```
I know the frog to be green.
```

b)  I see the frog being caught.

```
I know the frog to be being caught.
```

c)  The frog was seen being caught.

```
The frog was seen to be being caught.
```

I made some changes to the initial question.

I believe that the first sentences in each pair are correct, but as for the second ones I am not sure.
Could you, please, advise.

Comment: I am certainly not interested in wading through that table to look at all the different sentences you've exhibited: I don't know if others are. I have proposed this question be closed as being too unfocused.

Comment: Colin Fine, Ok, i understand

Comment: Mari-Lou A, ok, thank you! I wiil be searching these myself, for sure, but i have no idea how grammar calls such a construction, i do not know what i am searching.

Comment: I changed "I saw the frog being caught" to "I know the frog to be being caught” , because i came to the conclusion that "-ing" can be used with "to be" omited with verbs of sensual perception only.

Comment: I realise my wording could be misunderstood **I saw the frog being caught** Is grammatical, the Active voice would be, "I saw someone catching the frog”. It is (f) which is very very awkward sounding. I advise you to reduce  the examples to  one or two otherwise the community will close your question for lack of focus.

Comment: _I see the frog green_ is not idiomatic; we say _I see that the frog is green_.

Comment: Kate Bunting, would it be correct to say "I see the frog to be green"? i am trying to figure out in which of these cases "to be" is used. I found the rule that with the verbs of sense perception "to be"  is  omitted. Thank you!  Thank you for your comment!!!